# Sharing code between a silverlight and WinRT application

Tags: windows, silverlight, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm in the process of creating a silverlight app which will run in the browser and uses some data visualization stuff provided by ComponentArt. At some point I'd also like to create a a WinRT xaml/c# version so it can run as a windows store app all editions of Windows 8 including WindowsRT.

My question is how can I approach this to get maximum code-reusage between the 2 versions. I see no other way than having 2 versions (as I am tied to using componentart and can't use a html/js approach). In particular how portable will the xaml used in the silverlight app be to the windows store app?

Answer (score 2):

Your XAML is as portable as the features you use. You can't reuse same XAML files since they use different namespaces and xmlns URI schemes and also you will most likely want to make the UI slightly different since Silverlight is primarily Mouse+Keyboard UI and WinRT/XAML is primarily touch.

Make sure you use MVVM to be able to reuse a lot of the non-XAML code. When selecting which controls to use - make sure they are available in WinRT/XAML or have good alternatives. Some of the missing things I saw were `WriteableBitmap.Render()` method, `RadialGradientBrush`, `TypeConverterAttribute`,  `Style`/`Setter` bindings, `TreeView`, `DataGrid` or `GridSplitter` controls. Though there are open source versions of a lot of the missing controls - you will most likely want to use alternative UI design approaches for Windows Store Apps since these don't work well with touch.

For reference - I spent around 2-3 hours porting the `TreeView` control from Silverlight Toolkit to WinRT, around as much for the `Calendar` control and 20-30 hours to port the `Chart` control with its many kinds of data points and series - and that's on top of the original port by Mahmoud Moussa. Depending on the complexity of the features you use - the required effort will obviously grow. If you just use `Buttons, TextBoxes, TextBlocks, RadioButtons, CheckBoxes` etc. - you can mostly do copy&paste to port the XAML. I would also avoid retemplating the controls since template parts and visual states/visual state groups are slightly different between these platforms, so you would need to either redo the work or spend time correcting the templates.